# How to integrate Kafka Сonsumer in Keyсloak?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, keycloak, kafka-consumer-api, keycloak-spi

I need to create a custom SPI extension for keycloak, which should integrate Kafka Consumer. I need to read messages(userId, attributeKey, attributeValue) from Kafka topic and then update that user. But I still don’t understand how to teach keycloak to listen to topic Kafka all the time? Maybe someone has solved a similar problem or can give examples of solutions? I can solve this with an external microservice that will be integrated with Kafka Consumer, but I have to solve this inside keycloak, without using external microservices.

I created a custom provider based on ProviderFactory. I created an Apache Kafka Consumer configuration, but I was unable to run the Consumer within this SPI

Comment: Provide more info about what you have done and what is failing